# Suppress repeating values on subsequent rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
item_no parent   item_no_child   item_name   text
123                3              xxx       the item is resistant to water
123                5              yyy       The item is resistant to heat
123                6              zzz       The item is ....
```

I will be giving the parent item_no as input and retrieve child item no's. Now I have to check each child item's text and if they have same text I should not display the item_name else I should.

Comment: look up the LAG function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) analytic function is a neat way of implementing such distinct queries:

```
SELECT item_name
FROM   (SELECT item_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY text ORDER BY 1) AS rn
        FROM   items
        WHERE  item_no parent = 123)
WHERE  rn = 1
```

EDIT:
Some explanation, as requested in the comments - `row_number` is an analytic function (sometimes also referred to as a windowing function). It returns one result per row of input (like a row function), but takes into account all the other rows too (like an aggregate function). In this case, `row_number` simply returns the number of current row (i.e., a simple counter). This counting is done per different value of `text` (the `partition by` clause). `row_number` requires an `order by` clause so it knows in which order to count these rows. Since here we don't care about which row (per different value of `text`) comes first, I simply order by a constant `1`.

Comment: Could you please explain what that exactly does?? I mean what that row_number,partition does.