# sql query result format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Sorry for inconvenience,i thought i am simplifying the question but may be i made it more complex,previously the data was like this,

**Table:**

```
BRANCHCD       BAL1    BAL2   ACMCD
SH14           10        -      111
SH14           11        -      112
SH14            -         1     211
```

in one table had bal1 for acmcd  and bal2 for acmcd,onl one will be available at a time so don't  worry about that case,so and i need it in following format.

```
  BRANCHCD       BAL1    ACMCD   bal2  acmcd
    SH14           10      111      1    211
    SH14           11      112
```

if new rows added in Table are:

```
BRANCHCD       BAL1    BAL2   ACMCD
SH14                     2      212
SH14                     3      213
```

then o/p should be

```
  BRANCHCD       BAL1    ACMCD   bal2  acmcd
    SH14           10      111      1    211
    SH14           11      112      2    212
    SH14                            3    213
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425157/suppress-repeating-values-on-subsequent-rows

Comment: thanks for the reply i already tried that and it is not that much useful for my case..

Comment: i do not understand why bal2 and ACMCD should be null? what is the logic of your join?

Comment: when i am having tbl1 join with tbl2  and tbl1 with tbl3 separately then i have 2 rows from 1st join and 1 row from 2nd just need to merge them and get above result.

Comment: @Vaibhav why does the second row do not have data from the third table? why not the second row has values from third table and first don't? how do you know when the row should be joined and when not

Comment: Please provide more information about your current code, why you don't need duplicate data from  tbl3 but it is OK for duplicates from tbl1? as Zynon said it seems you have more columns participated in your joins

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience please check the question,i edited it @hmmftg

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience please check the question,i edited it @hotfix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume your desired output is to basically compress the new records to show them juxtaposed rather than as new entries below. So, there is no relation between `acmcd = 112`  and `acmcd = 212` other than the fact that they are 2nd  available entries under respective "bal"s for a `branchcd`  in the table. It also appears that the column `acmcd` gets a unique value for each newly added row ( sequentially or not).

If the above statements are true, you could use `row_number()` to generate ids for each unique `acmcds` for a given `BRANCHCD`. Creating bal1 and bal2 records as separate data sets through a cte or sub-query, we could do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` on `row_number`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa1c/15)

**Query**:

```
WITH a 
     AS (SELECT row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY branchcd 
                    ORDER BY acmcd ) AS rn, 
                t.* 
         FROM   t 
         WHERE  bal1 IS NOT NULL), 
     b 
     AS (SELECT row_number() 
                  OVER( 
                    partition BY branchcd 
                    ORDER BY acmcd ) AS rn, 
                t.* 
         FROM   t 
         WHERE  bal2 IS NOT NULL) 
SELECT COALESCE(a.branchcd,b.branchcd) as branchcd,
       a.bal1, 
       a.acmcd, 
       b.bal2, 
       b.acmcd 
FROM   a 
       FULL OUTER JOIN b 
                    ON ( a.branchcd = b.branchcd 
                         AND a.rn = b.rn )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fa1c/15/0)**:

```
| BRANCHCD |   BAL1 |  ACMCD | BAL2 | ACMCD |
|----------|--------|--------|------|-------|
|     SH14 |     10 |    111 |    1 |   211 |
|     SH14 |     11 |    112 |    2 |   212 |
|     SH14 | (null) | (null) |    3 |   213 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your tables have more columns that you aren't sharing with us, it seems you need to add to your left join of table C something that compares the last two digits of ACMCD. Otherwise you aren't giving any indication to the query as to how those records are related.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience please check the question,i edited it